# How to set background to div

Tags: html, css

I tried to set image in background of a div but disappeared! I want the background image covers all page, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
div {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/094/491/original/polygonal-texture-background-vector.jpg');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very basics stuff. See this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for this make parents 100% by:

```
html,body{width:100%;height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    }
```

---

```
<div>
   <img src="img1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just attach it to the body directly :

```
body {
    background-image: url("img_link");
}
```

Hope this helps.